# Incorporating MathML in Google Blogger posts

Tags: latex, blogs, mathml

I'd like to format maths equations using MathML, with LaTeX-like syntax, in my blog posts hosted by Google Blogger; but references, on Google's site and elsewhere, to articles on how to conveniently do this seem non-existent.

The few articles I've found, on MathML generally, presupposes one can control the contents of an entire page, for example putting tokens in the "<html>" tag, which I don't think applies to Google Blogger.

The best site I've found is Ionel Alexandru's code at http://www.fmath.info/ But even there the documentation is very sparse and it isn't obvious how one would use his
scripts/packages for this.

Maybe I'm just being thick. But surely people must be using MathML in Google Blogger, and if so I'd be very interested in references to how it can best be done (preferably via an XML solution rather than dozens of little inline images in the text !)

Failing that, are there standard "register and start blogging" facilities/sites other than Google Blogger that make it easy to use MathML or where it is available as standard?

Cheers

John R Ramsden

Comment: This is off-topic, but Wordpress has support for LaTeX encoding, like so: `$ \ln(e) = 1 $`

Answer (score 3):

I've written a javascript module, jqmath, to do what you want.  See http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html.

Instructions on how to use it in Google Blogger are at http://mathscribetheblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/jqmath-in-blogger.html.

By the way, those instructions do have you edit your `<html>` tag, which Google Blogger happily let me do.  (I just did it to add a MathML namespace prefix for the MathPlayer plugin for Internet Explorer, so actually things would work ok, but less well, without it.)

I hope you like this.  If you have any problems, post the link to your blog, and I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I use Peter Jipsen;s script, modified a bit, to get mathml into blogger

http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.com/2007/04/testing-interface.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems the most wellknown is Math jax? [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/)